# Gitlab adding commit trailer via VSCode Source Control

Tags: git, gitlab

We are trying to automatically generate changelog using Gitlab Changelog API.

In order to generate the Changelog, commit messages must have trailer such as `Changelog: added` or `Changelog: fixed`.

This is not an issue. I can add a trailer using cmd for example, after I finished developing a feature, I can do the following:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Finally finished developing feature #1" --trailer "Changelog: added"
git push
```

And I can see this in the changelog without any issues.

However, other colleagues are not using cmd to stash all changes, make commits and pushes. They rely on `VScode Source Control` or other tools such as `git extensions` or `fork`.

I have tried to make a commit message with a trailer in the VSCode source control as shown below:
[image]

See the image below:
[image]

The image above shows 3 commits. 2 of them were performed using VSCode Source Control and 1 was performed using cmd. When I try to generate changelog, the only visible commit is the one that is performed via cmd.

```
PS C:\Users\petrikas.lu\Desktop\WORK\gitchangelog-test\my_project> curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:9KyaH8hXhr8H-dxzGzaT" "https://xxx-gitlab.xxxxxxxx.lt/api/v4/projects/121/repository/changelog?version=3.2.0"
{"notes":"## 3.2.0 (2023-12-18)\n\n### added (1 change)\n\n- [adding trailer via cmd line](embeded-programmers/gitchangelog-test@5263ee4c0520fc050ef8bb4831a79652f3b8f3cf)\n"}
```

I would really apreciate if someone could shed some light on how to properly add trailers so the Gitlab changelog API can detect it. I have no problem doing it via cmd but I also want to know how to do it using other methods.